# What is the use of Hidden folders in home?

Tags: files, home-directory, system-settings

I saw so many hidden folders when I pressed Ctrl+H in my home folder !
their names are starting with a dot (.) ! like .themes , .config and etc..
Can I please get to know what can I do with those folders ?
Or should I delete those ?

Comment: these folder contain configuration files and temporary data used by software, which you dont need to access directly. so they are kept hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything related to a user is stored in their home. That includes configurations, settings, the theme you chose but also bookmarks and so on. So there are lots of files in there you need not  worry about.

**Leave them as they are**. Deleting them will delete your configuration for the program you deleted it for. If you delete the chromuim directory you basically will remove your profile (bookmarks, saved passwords, saved tabs).

So I images that since you most times do not need to bother with them and to not clog up the view when looking at your /home/ directory in Nautilus or from command line these have a dot in front of them and kept out of view. If you do need them you probably also know they will be hidden anyways.

You can add non-dot files yourself by adding them to a file called ".hidden". Nautilus will remove those from view if you are not using control+h to view hidden files.